# How best to create tabbed content component, folder, method structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, styled-components

I'm trying to build a tabbed content component but not sure on how best to proceed with this.

I have an object array such as below which can take in any number

```
tabs= {[
  {
    "title": "Some title 1",
    "otherComponents": [
      <Title ... />,
      <Paragraph... />
    ]
  },
    ...
    ...
    ...
}]
```

I have a feeling that I need to firstly focus on displaying the tab.title and then display the tab.contents in `otherComponents`. but not sure on how i'd link the two together in able to identify the active tab and which contents to display.. Any help in the folder structure for this components and what kind of function would bet needed would be greatly appreciated as I'm not sure on the best approach for this. What would you suggest to focus on first?

I would guess the following function: `getTabHeaders` and `getTabContents` and then display them below each other?

I have the following folder structure below

-tabbed-content
     -tabbed-content.js
     -tab-content.js
     -tab-headers

Not sure if they should all go into the main file which is `tabbed-content`.

in `tabbed-content` I have something like the following

```
  getTabbedContent() {
    const {
    tabs,
  } = this.props;

  const numberOfTabs = Object.keys(tabs).length;

  return (
    <StyledTabbedContent>
      { tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <TabHeader
          key={uuidv1()}
          title={tab.title}
          tabNumber={1+ index}
          numberOfTabs={numberOfTabs}
        />
        ),
      )}
    </StyledTabbedContent>
  );
  }
```

in `tab-header` I have the following

```
  render() {
    const { numberOfTabs, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <StyledTab 
        numberOfTabs={numberOfTabs}
      >
          <StyledTitle>{title}</StyledTitle>
      </StyledTab>     
    ) 
  }
}
```

What I was think was having in `tab-content` something similar to the above but not sure howd id link the both of them together... which makes me think I'm going down the wrong path... Which is why i'm asking for a folder structure/method structure or a plan on what to do first to tackle the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to create a more generic Tabbar component. In your app you might want to do the following:

```
<TabbedContent>
  <div label="Tab 1"> ... individual content goes here ... </div>
  <div label="Tab 2"> ... individual content goes here ... </div>
  <div label="Tab 3"> ... individual content goes here ... </div>
</TabbedContent>
```

The TabbedContent component then takes care of the rest:

1. parsing children
2. create tabs from label property
3. handling the click logic
4. yes, your can use styled-components

For this example I will not use react Refs and I will do the hacky way with .bind. SO PLEASE, you should fix this by yourself ;) This is just to push you in the right direction. If you have a version without .bind you could update my post :)

**Your TabbedContent component should look like this:**

```
export default class TabbedContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // get the label from the first child
    const { children } = this.props
    const firstChild = children && children[0] 

    if (firstChild){
      // save active label in state
      const { label } = firstChild.props
      this.state = { activeTab: label }
    }

  }

}
```

The render method of TabbedContent should return the following:

```
const {
  onClickTabItem,
  props: { children },
  state: { activeTab },
} = this

return (
<Tabs>
  <TabList>
    {children.map((child) => {
      const { label } = child.props
      return (
        <Tab
          active={label === activeTab}
          key={label}
          onClick={onClickTabItem.bind(this, label)}
        >
          {label}
        </Tab>
      )
    })}
  </TabList>
  <TabContent>
    {children.map((child) => {
      if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined
      return child.props.children
    })}
  </TabContent>
</Tabs>
)
```

Add a onClickTabItem method to the component and set the state, whenever its getting called:

```
onClickTabItem = (tab) => {
  this.setState({ activeTab: tab })
}
```

Your `Tab` styled-component should implement a behaviour for the property `active`:

```
${props => props.active && css`
  background: black;
  color: white;
`}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but for `onClickTabItem` you have put `..{ activeTab: tab }` what is `tab` and where are you getting this?

Comment: I overhand the label in onClick={} on Tab. The label I am getting from the generic containers I added as children. (First code block I posted)